# Cuda Matrix Example Block Size

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cuda, gpu

I just started learning CUDA and I have been looking at examples on NVIDIA's website. Specifically, I have implemented the non-shared version of the matrix multiply (the first sample is the non-shared version even though it is in the shared memory section):

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory

I am having a problem with the output when I change the block sizes. NVIDIA's code has a default block size of 16 and this gives me the correct output when I multiply two matrices. However, if I change the block size to anything above 16 (while still being a multiple of 16), I get an output of zero for all elements in the matrix. I tested this on my laptop too and noticed the same results for anything over 32 rather than 16. Could someone explain what is happening? I have two 9800GTX+ video cards in SLI and so I should have a maximum block size of (512,512,1). Why can I only do 16?

Also, I am noticing the same behavior in the shared version of the matrix multiplication (also on the NVIDIA page).

I didn't post my code because I get the same problem if I directly copy the code from the NVIDIA site.

I would really appreciate any help with this or with resources to learn more about these kinds of CUDA details.

Thank you!

I have attached the code as requested:

```
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include <cuda.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <math.h>

    // This is an example CUDA program that compares the timings of a matrix multiplication.
    // The comparisons are between the CPU, GPU, and the GPU with shared memory.

    #define BLOCK_SIZE 32

    typedef struct {

    int width;
    int height;
    int stride;
    float* elements;

    } Matrix;

    typedef void (*FuncPtr)(Matrix& A, Matrix& B, Matrix& C);

    void multiplyMatrix(Matrix& A, Matrix& B, Matrix& C);

    // Helper declarations
    void initializeMatrix(Matrix& A, int rows, int cols, float val);
    void copyMatrix(Matrix& dest, Matrix& src);
    void freeMatrix(Matrix& A);
    void printError(cudaError_t err);
    void printMat(Matrix& A);
    void setVal(Matrix& A, float val);
    double applyMultFunc(FuncPtr func, Matrix& A, Matrix& B, Matrix& C, int numOfIters);

    // CUDA declarations
    __global__ void cudaMultMat(Matrix A, Matrix B, Matrix C);


   int main() {

       printf("Beginning Matrix Multiplication Comparison\n");

       // Initialize matrix
       Matrix A, B, C;
       int rowsA = 32;
       int colsA = 32;
       int colsB = 32;
       initializeMatrix(A, rowsA, colsA, 5.0f);
       initializeMatrix(B, colsA, colsB, 2.0f);
       initializeMatrix(C, rowsA, colsB, 0.0f);

       // C = A * B using CPU, GPU, and GPU with shared memory
       FuncPtr gpuMatMult = &multiplyMatrix;
       int numOfIterations = 100;
       double multTime = applyMultFunc(gpuMatMult, A, B, C, numOfIterations);

       printMat(C); 

       // Update user
       printf("Normal Mat Mult Time: %f\n", multTime);


       // Cleanup
       freeMatrix(A);
       freeMatrix(B);
       freeMatrix(C);

       printf("\nPress Enter to continue...\n");
       getchar();

       return 0;

  }

  void multiplyMatrix(Matrix& A, Matrix& B, Matrix& C) {

    // Initialize device matrices
    Matrix deviceA, deviceB, deviceC;
    copyMatrix(deviceA, A);
    copyMatrix(deviceB, B);
    copyMatrix(deviceC, C);

    // Initialize number of blocks and threads
    dim3 numOfThreadsPerBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
    int xSize = (C.width + numOfThreadsPerBlock.x - 1) / numOfThreadsPerBlock.x;
    int ySize = (C.height + numOfThreadsPerBlock.y - 1) / numOfThreadsPerBlock.y;
    dim3 numOfBlocks(xSize, ySize);

    // Call CUDA kernel
    cudaMultMat<<<numOfBlocks, numOfThreadsPerBlock>>>(deviceA, deviceB, deviceC);
    printError(cudaThreadSynchronize());
    printError(cudaMemcpy(C.elements, deviceC.elements, C.height * C.width * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    // Free cuda memory
    printError(cudaFree(deviceA.elements));
    printError(cudaFree(deviceB.elements));
    printError(cudaFree(deviceC.elements));

  }



 // CUDA definitions

 // GPU matrix multiplication (non-shared memory)
 __global__ void cudaMultMat(Matrix A, Matrix B, Matrix C) {

    // If the matrices are of the wrong size then return
    if(A.width != B.height) {
        return;
    }

    // Initialize the indexes into the grid
    int col = (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x) + threadIdx.x;
    int row = (blockDim.y * blockIdx.y) + threadIdx.y;

    // Initialize the result
    float cVal = 0.0f;

    // Find the result for the dot product of a row of A and a column of B
    for(int i = 0; i < A.width; i++) {

        cVal += A.elements[row * A.width + i] * B.elements[i * B.width + col];

     }

     // If we are in bounds then save the result
     if(row < C.height && col < C.width) {
        C.elements[row * C.width + col] = cVal;
     }

  } 

  // Helper functions
  void initializeMatrix(Matrix& A, int rows, int cols, float val) {

    A.width = cols;
    A.height = rows;
    A.stride = A.width;
    int numOfElements = A.width * A.height;
    A.elements = (float*) malloc(numOfElements * sizeof(float));
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++) {
        A.elements[i] = val;
    }

   }

   void copyMatrix(Matrix& dest, Matrix& src) {

    dest.width = src.width;
    dest.height = src.height;
    dest.stride = src.stride;
    int size = src.width * src.height * sizeof(float);
    printError(cudaMalloc(&dest.elements, size)); 
    printError(cudaMemcpy(dest.elements, src.elements, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

   }

   void freeMatrix(Matrix& A) {
    free(A.elements);
   }

   void printError(cudaError_t err) {
    if(err != 0) {
        printf("CUDA ERROR: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        getchar();
    }

    }

    void printMat(Matrix& A) {

    printf("*********************************\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < A.height; i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < A.width; j++) {
             int index = i * A.width + j;
             printf("%2.1f, ", A.elements[index]); 
         }
         printf("\n");
     }

  }

  void setVal(Matrix& A, float val) {

     for(int i = 0; i < A.width * A.height; i++) {
          A.elements[i] = val;
     }

  }

  double applyMultFunc(FuncPtr func, Matrix& A, Matrix& B, Matrix& C, int numOfIters) {

    clock_t startTime = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfIters; i++) {
        func(A, B, C);
     } 
     clock_t endTime = clock();
     return (double) (endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

   }
```

Comment: please post your code, its important to see the size of matrices you are using or grid size, and a lot of other things due to which this can happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're exceeding the threads per block specification of your GPU when you increase the block sizes.

The 9800GTX has a limit of 512 threads per block, regardless of how you create the block.  16*16 = 256 which is OK.  32 x 32 = 1024 which is not OK.  In this case the kernel fails to run and  so the output is not correct.

Your laptop probably has a newer GPU which supports 1024 threads per block, so 32 x 32 is OK but anything larger is not.

If you add [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) to the code you can confirm this.  Note that this code appears to have cuda error checking,  but the checking implemented on the kernel call is incoomplete.  Study the link I gave and you will see the difference.  If you modify the code with complete error checking, you will see the error.

Answer (score 0):

if your GPU's compute capability is 1.0/1.1, you can have at most 512 threads per block. But in new GPU device, every block can have at most 1024 threads.